# How to decode a byte[] using Base64 in Ballerina?

Tags: base64, decode, ballerina

I am passing an encoded file as a `http:Request request` for a ballerina REST service. I need to decode the binary payload of the `request` using `Base64` in order to upload it to a file server. I was unable to find a way to decode a `byte[]` using `Base64`. Here is my sample code.

```
resource function post\-file(http:Request request) returns string|error {
    byte[]|http:ClientError binaryPayload = request.getBinaryPayload();
    if binaryPayload is http:ClientError {
        return error("Error in payload");
    }

    // Now I need to decode the binaryPayload into a byte[]
    // Tried following options. But seems like those options are not available in Swan Lake Update 3

    // byte[] decodedPayload = check encoding:base64Decode(binaryPayload);
    // byte[] decodedPayload = io:base64Decode(encodedPayload);


    // How to do this in a correct way?

    return "success";
}
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ballerina/mime` library for encoding/decoding `byte[]` values.

```
import ballerina/mime; // Make sure to import the mime package

// ...

byte[] decodedPayload = check mime:base64Decode(binaryPayload);
```